# Image of a continuous function from the reals to the reals

Tags: continuity, connectedness

I know the image of a connected set in $\mathbb{R}$ under a continuous function to $\mathbb{R}$ is also a connected set- I.e intervals map to intervals. But what about the image of a disconnected set? Not necessarily connected? E.g a domain of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$?

Comment: What about constant functions? Also your question is a little vague. I would suggest rewording it so that it is more clear.

Comment: So it's not necessarily disconnected.

Comment: $$\sin\colon \  \left(0,\,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cup \left(2\pi,\,\frac{5\pi}{2}\right)\to (0,\,1).$$

Comment: Correct. If your domain is disconnected then you don't have any idea about its image unless you inspect it. Constant functions always have connected image, and a function like $x^3$ would map $(-1,0) \cup (0,1)$ into a disconnected set.